# What is the spring.cloud.stream.function.reactive property for?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I use reactive environment and my message communication is successful without it. I found this property and I have not found any information from documentation or comment in the code. What is the goal of this property?

I was already debugging this and found that the library can access this attribute. Bean's name will be used. So, my example I make is like that.

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: beanFunctionInCode
    stream:
      function:
        reactive: # <---
          beanFunctionInCode: true
```

Comment: I am not sure where you found it as it does not exist.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky Exists. See: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/main/core/spring-cloud-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/StreamFunctionProperties.java#L117

Comment: Ofc, I/We use up-to-date boot/cloud versions.

Comment: StreamFunctionProperties should no longer be a publicly exposed configuration properties. It is strictly for internal use. I am fixing it